# how do I give a slide down effects for the full width submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a navigation with full width submenu
but the drop down is too hard. I want it to be like a slide down with easing
this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/bK9mF/

```
body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
 /* not very relevant styling */
  h1 {
font-size: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
 }
 .container {
position: relative;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
width: 75%;
 }
 .header {
background: #eee;
 }
 .nav {
background: #ccc;
 }
 /* relevant styling */
  body {
overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 /* trick from css-tricks comments */

 /* FIRST LEVEL */
  .nav > ul > li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding: 3px 10px 3px 0;
z-index: 100;
 }
 /* SECOND LEVEL */
  .nav > ul > li > ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 100%;
padding: 0 1000em;
/* trick from css-tricks comments */
margin: 0 -1000em;
/* trick from css-tricks comments */
z-index: 101;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
background: rgba(255, 240, 240, 0.8);
 }
 .nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
 }
 .nav > ul > li > ul > li {
padding: 3px 0;
 }
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a real jsfiddle please...

Comment: I'm sorry as I forgot to add the fiddle.

Comment: You need to try on your own and be helped by us only if you encounter a **specific** problem

Comment: I updated this http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/bK9mF/4/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to replace visibility and opacity with `display:none;` because display:none hides elements, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there.

I recommend you to use jQuery instead of CSS3 `transition` property because it is not supported by Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions and Chrome 25, and earlier versions, requires the prefix `-webkit-` and other browsers like Opera Mini doesn't support transition.
[Source: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions ]

You have to use jquery `.slideToggle()` method to animate the drop down menu.

```
function deactivateAll(item) {
    $("li").not(item).each(function(index, elem) {
        if ($(elem).hasClass("active")) {
            toggle(elem);
        }
    });
}

function toggle(elem) {
    $(elem).find("ul.submenu").stop(true, true).slideToggle("fast");
    $(elem).toggleClass("active");
} 

$(".container li").on("hover", function(e) {
    deactivateAll(this);
    toggle(this);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bK9mF/6/).